# what are some good greeking fonts for demonstrating text

Tags: font-recommendation

So i am making mock ups for website, and i want to show some text. I want to use some font that make it look like it's a text but not really anything readable. Like a cursive line with personality that looks like it is something written from distance in real life but you have to come close to read it but it somewhat consistent and precise enough to look that's not hand written.

something like this but more professional...
[image]

[image]

Comment: google is seriously failing me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are referring to is called ['greeking' and is typically done with lorem ipsum](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/2290/what-does-the-filler-text-lorem-ipsum-mean), which is a fake latin-looking gibberish.

So one option to use your preferred typeface, but lorem ipsum as your content.

Another option that I often use is 'xxxxxxx' text. This isn't nearly as pretty, but it's blatantly obvious that it's not real text. So something like: Xxxxxx xxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx xxx xx xxxxxx x xxxx.

The advantage is there is no mistaking that for real text. I've seen cases where Lorem Ipsum accidentally made it into production.

But to answer your specific question, there are actual fonts for this as well:

[Blokkfont](http://blokkfont.com/) uses a style that is reminiscent of the marker comp days where to show blocks of text, you'd simply use solid lines (drawn with your marker).

[Lettererror](http://letterror.com/fontcatalog/free-fonts/) has a few options that emulate sketchy scribbles.

And there are others. Google 'greeking font'.

Comment: Lettererror is very close :D

Comment: If anyone finds more similar font let me know here..